# How to improve the accuracy of support vector machine algorithms in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, python, svm, prediction, accuracy

I am working with a machine learning project named "Diabetes prediction using support vector machine". In this project I have used Pima Indians Diabetes Database. Using SVM I have got 78% training and 77% test accuracy. I want to improve the accuracy.

[Here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1oxnhMTlomJ4HVhPuowpPFyMt1mwuOuQo?usp=sharing) is the followed code.

How can I improve accuracy?
Can anyone help me?

Comment: You currently seem to not be doing any exploratory data analysis to better understand the data. I would start with that to understand the data and see what patterns are correlated with the label you're trying to predict. In addition, using the knowledge you gained from your EDA try to improve your feature engineering to create new features that are useful for your model.

Comment: You may also try Hyperparameter tuning of C & Gamma parameter

Comment: It might also be useful to print the confusion matrix on the test set predictions, to see what kind of error happens. Btw accuracy is not a great measure for an imbalanced dataset, precision/recall/f-score would be more informative.

Comment: First of all there is a major biais problem on your code (which might help getting a higher or a lower accuracy). You are scaling your entire dataset which leads to statistics biais. Your train part is being scaled using test data. The scaling comes after the split. Another point to keep in mind your test accucary is pretty great knwoing that is slightly lower from your train. You can't beat the train accuracy. Following Oxbowerce ; Ashwiniku918 and Erwan advice you should get better results.